Whose turn is it?
This puzzle builds around some similar ideas as in my last one, but here I was able to flesh out the story in the critical sequence a bit more. Can you tell whose turn it is in this position? And, while you're at it:
Can you determine the last 32 single moves?

As always, please provide your reasoning and a proof game in your answer. Have fun with this! I certainly did :)

Balance of captures:
Black (3): g7xf6; exd; hxg
White (2): e2xf3; cxd (and promoted by d8)
Reasoning:
To return the Black King, you need to return e2xf3. This is the critical move because White and Black only has a limited number of pawn retractions before this is done.
To do this, you need to bring Bishop f1 home.
g3 will not give us a bishop, so it remains to consider d7xBe6.
For this we must first lower the d8 pawn and bring home the c8 bishop.
For the first, we need wQh7, which bNe8 can release. For the second, we need bBh3, which wNg7 can release, which bNe8 can release. But bNe8 cannot free two people.
Therefore, first we will release the queen, and the bishop will be released by the other knight received after the return of the white cxd.
With all this in mind, we can say how far we can move the pawns:

bPa4-a5 (leave the way home for bRa8)
bPg3-g5 (if bPg6, then after bNg7 and bNh7, the wKh6 cannot exit through h5 due to a double check on h5)
wPb6-b4 (leave the way home for wRa1, wBc1)
wPc-c2

And then we can easily play back the moves until the return of the critical move е2xf3.
Solution:

... Nd6-e8 2. b5-b6 Ne4-d6 3. b4-b5(!) Ng5-e4 4. Qd3-h7 Nh7-g5+ 5. Qd8-d3 g4-g3 6. d7-d8=Q g5-g4(!) 7. c6xNd7 (of course, it would be more convenient to revive the black knight on d6, but then there would not be enough black pawn moves to retract; we have only one move left: a4-a5, which we will need at the end)

.7. ... Nb6-d7 8. c5-c6 Nc8-b6 9. c4-c5 Nd6-c8 10. c3-c4 Ne8-d6 11. Ne6-g7 Ng7-e8+ 12. Nf4-e6 Bc8-h3 13. Nh3-f4+ e6-e5 14. c2-c3(!) d7xBe6 15. Bc4-e6 a5-a4(!) 16. Bf1-c4 Kg4-h4 17. e2xQf3+ etc (wh4-h5; wKh5-h6)
In general, you can make sure that all the moves are unique. The pieces can follow the only possible route, the pace of the pawns cannot be rearranged.
To follow along, paste the FEN 4nbRr/1pp1ppNQ/1P3p1K/4p2P/p6k/5Ppb/P2P1PPR/6Br and the solution into Retractor 2.

Good job finding that solution! And also thanks for bringing it into a more welcoming format :)
